# Pandas Remove Duplicated Columns

Tags: python, excel, pandas, filter

I am playing with an excel spreadsheet that is comparing the the value of two items across different currencies. The spreadsheet headings are as below:

**USD USD DIFFERENCE | GBP GBP DIFFERENCE | JPY JPY DIFFERENCE .......**

When I import this to pandas and create a dataframe it creates headings named Difference.1, Difference.2, Difference.3...., Difference.n

I want to remove all headings named **DIFFERENCE**

Note all the difference headings are uniquely named

Comment: We'll need a bit more info to go on. What code have you tried? Are you using the `header` option?

Comment: passing `sep='\t'` might do the trick: `pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t')`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can refer to this link for pandas [df.drop functions](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)
what we will do is below.

1. search for all the columns name with **DIFFERENCE**
2. generate a list with all these names in it
3. drop columns that contain these names

// get a new df that contains only name with DIFFERENCE in it

```
df2 = df.filter(like='DIFFERENCE ', axis=1)
```

// generate a list for all these column name

```
x = []
for col in df2.columns:
    x.append(col)
```

// drop columns with these names in x

```
df.drop(columns=x)
```

// **OR** you can keep a new df for these updated information

```
df3 = df.drop(columns=x)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe all you need is remove columns that contain 'DIFFERENCE' in it names. In this case you can simply do:

```py
    df = pd.read_csv("../path/to/your/file.csv")
    df = df[df.columns.drop(list(df.filter(regex='DIFFERENCE')))]
```

#### Example

If you have something like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"a1": [1,2,3], "a2":[1,1,1], "b":[2,4,6]})
print(df)

Out:
   a1  a2  b
0   1   1  2
1   2   1  4
2   3   1  6
```

Further step is

```py
df = df[df.columns.drop(list(df.filter(regex='a')))]
print(df)

Out:
   b
0  2
1  4
2  6
```

You can read more about [pandas.DataFrame.drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)